# Ukelele not working on High Sierra

Tags: keyboard, high-sierra, system-settings, internationalization, ukelele

I'm trying to switch to a Hungarian keyboard layout in High Sierra.

I downloaded Ukelele for this and got a custom layout which I installed and then selected in System Preferences.

Unfortunately this does not work nor selecting the "Appl" Hungarian QWERTY layout. They keys on my keyboard enter the same thing regardless of what I choose here, even with other languages.

Any ideas?

I'm on a MacBook Air

Comment: Have you checked with the Ukelele developer or used their support forum (they indicate how to get support on their webpage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have no problem making Hungarian Qwerty work. Have you verified that the correct layout is showing in the "flag" menu at the top right of the screen when you are trying to type, like this:

[image]

To see the "flag" menu, you check the box for "Show Input Menu in Menu Bar" in system preferences/keyboard/input sources.

(Selecting something in system preferences/keyboard/input source does not accomplish anything other than show you a picture of the layout).

Ukelele is for making a custom keyboard layout.  Do you really need to do that for some reason?

Comment: Not sure if I need a custom one. I have an external USB keyboard and want to use it for two separate machines so every key is the same etc.

Comment: However I dont see the flag while typing. How can then I actually set up what language if not in input source? I don't see any other options, I just selected the language there.

Comment: @breakline To see the "flag" menu, you check the box for "Show Input Menu in Menu Bar" in system preferences/keyboard/input sources.

Comment: @breakline If your external keyboard in QWERTZ you need to use the Hungarian input source instead of Hungarian QWERTY.

Comment: Thanks, I had to restart but the flag appeared eventually